# How to set Debug Symbol Path via .props file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After a restructuring of our project, all the 3rd-party libraries ended up in a single system-wide directory. A set of .props files ensures that the include-directories, library-directories, prepocessor definitions, etc. are set correctly upon including such a .props file.

Currently we advise developers to specify the symbol paths by hand using Visual Studio -> Menu Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols. But when moving the 3rd-party libraries to another folder, or when seting up a second set for testing, we have to change this manually.

Is it possible, and how, to specify the debug symbol path in a .props file? And how?
And of course, is it possible to set the sourcepath (for debugging) in a .props file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.  It is a VS setting, not a project setting.

In general it doesn't make sense to have this problem.  If these libraries are static link libraries then their .pdb files get merged into the .pdb file for the final executable.  If they are DLLs then there needs to be a way for the operating system to find the DLL at runtime.  In which case the debugger also won't have any trouble finding the .pdb file for the DLL.

You can diagnose .pdb searching problems for DLLs with Debug + Windows + Modules.  Right-click the DLL and select "Symbol Load Information".  It shows you where the debugger searched for the .pdb

Comment: Just to clarify your statement "In which case the debugger also won't have any trouble finding the .pdb file for the DLL."  Would extending the %PATH% var also work for the symbols?

Comment: That's not the way it works, the debugger has several places it looks for the .pdb.  Including the same directory the DLL was loaded from and the original build location.  Use the Symbol Load Information dialog as I recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've found a workaround, by putting the relevant .pdbs next to the .dlls and using %PATH% to find those dlls (and pdbs)